# Regex: Searching for words with '%' at the beginning

Tags: regex

I've been trying to figure this out myself but I'm afraid Regular Expressions just aren't my thing. In this sample string: **"My name is %name and I live in $address."** I'm trying to get the words which begin with **"%"** then replace them with their values in `$name` or `$address` depending on what word was found in the regex. The new string is then returned complete with the replaced values.

**Should not return words like:** *aaa%aaa* (% isn't the first character) and *\%word* (the % is escaped)

**This is in PHP.** I'm using this since I'm grabbing the data from a ***.ini** file where everything is a string. I remove the $_POST example so it's not misleading.

Comment: You haven’t defined a "word".  You haven’t included which programming language or library you are using in the tagset.  Your question is unanswerable as written.

Comment: I'm assuming PHP but why do you need to use a regex to match this? I think a simple string concat would be easier if I'm reading this right. Could you please clarify your question some.

Comment: What the hell is a bloody word?  Is “shouldn’t” a word?  How about “shouldn’t’ve”?  Is “MᶜKinley” a word? Is “tender-hearted” a word?  Is “niño” a word? What about “façade”?  Is “Outer Limits” a word?  Is “_________” a word?  Is “3.14159” a word?  Is “π” a word?  Is “1/2” a word? **Qu’est-ce que c’est qu’un *word*?** Enquiring minds want to know.

Comment: this sentence has five words. A word is contiguous characters followed by a space as in any programming language :)

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: Then the string `"""""""` is a word, by your definition.

Comment: OK guys, move on to the chat. This is not a discussion board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should do fine:

```
(?<!\\|\w)%\w+
```

However it's usually a bad thing to not sanitize $_POST/$_GET before display/whatever.

Comment: This actually doesn't allow for an escaped escaped. `\\%test` will not pass and `%%test` will pass. But, that might be ok with the OP.

Comment: Oh, that's right. This doesn't allow for  \\%test or %%test at all.

Comment: @sln/enchance: yeah forgot to mention that. Feel free to accept nlp's answer and I'll just delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript or similar REGEX engines you could use:

```
\B(%\w+)\b
```

**Edit:**
In this case, the final `\b` is optional, since `\w` will match all chars needed and stop in any non word char as @tchrist pointed out.

**Edit 2:** This will not match `\%name`:

```
(?:^|\s)(%\w+)
```

Comment: What in the world is that final `\b` for?

Comment: Word boundary. In this case is optional because of the multi-word specification. Thanks for pointing out. I will add an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it possibly works. This align's on even escapes. -

`(?<!\\)(?:\\.)*(?<![%\w])%(\w+)`

expanded -

```
(?<!\\)     # Not an escape behind us
(?:\\.)*    # 0 or many esc plus anything
(?<![%\w])  # not % nor \w behind us
%(\w+)      # % then capture grp1 bunch of word chars
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would be helpful.

```
$string = "Hello %name from %city ";

$name = "Joe";
$city = "Boston";
$array = array();


preg_match("/%\w+/",$string,$array);

foreach($array as $string1)
               echo "match: ".$string1;
```

Comment: That doesn't handle `\%please \%don't \%switch \%these` correctly.

Comment: This will match `anythingHere%anyOtherThing`.

Comment: It is not prefect soluton, just a start. You comment is correct